# Is Fancybox no good on BlackBerry 10?

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2

I don't have a BB10 device, but I am using the BB Simulator (v10.1).

If you go to fancyapps.com on the simulator (or a real device if you have one), and click any of the example Fancybox links (e.g. open an image inside a Fancybox) then not one of them will work. Clicking an image just opens the image in the page and clicking a link does literally nothing.

The BB PlayBook and BB OS 7 both work perfectly.

Of course I am having a problem in developing something, but thought this was the best example to give.

I'm sure it's BB's fault, but what can be done?

JS is turned on, before anyone asks.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you figure it out?